# How to convert array values 0 and 255 to corresponding 0 and 1 array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an image represented as numpy array which has values of 0 and 255 (no other value within the range). What is the best way to convert it to 0 and 1 array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
my_array = np.array([255,255,0,0])
my_array = my_array / 255
```

Will output

```
array([ 1., 1., 0., 0.])
```

In other words, it will work to normalize all values in the range of 0-255 (even though you said it's the only 2 values, it will work for everything in between as well, while keeping the ratios)

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a job for [`numpy.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html):

```
>>> a = np.array([0, 255, 0, 255, 255, 0])
>>> a.clip(max=1)
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0])
```

From the docs:

> Given an interval, **values outside the interval are clipped to the interval edges**. For example, if an interval of [0, 1] is specified, values smaller than 0 become 0, and values larger than 1 become 1.

Answer (score 2):

Because there are so many answers that give the right answer, I just wanted to test the different approaches and decide which is the best in terms of computational cost. I wrote the following code that creates a given data set, which is an image of 0 and 255 values, placed at random, and then I study the mean elapsed time for each proposed algorithm, varying the number of pixels of the image (note that I use the mean to reduce the noise in the measurement):

```
import numpy as np
import time

times1_all = [] 
times2_all = []
times3_all = []


for i in xrange(20):
    times1 = []
    times2 = []
    times3 = []

    xsizes = np.arange(100,10000,500)
    print len(xsizes)
    for xsize in xsizes:
        #Create the dataset                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        ysize = xsize
        xrand = np.random.randint(0,xsize, xsize)
        yrand = np.random.randint(0,ysize, xsize)
        a = np.zeros([xsize,ysize])
        a[xrand, yrand] = 255

        start = time.time()
        b = (a == 255).astype('int')
        stop = time.time()
        time1 = stop-start

        start = time.time()
        b = a/255
        stop = time.time()
        time2 = stop-start

        start = time.time()
        b = a.clip(max=1)
        stop = time.time()
        time3 = stop-start
        print time3

        times1.append(time1)
        times2.append(time2)
        times3.append(time3)
        print 'Elapsed times --> (1)/(1)=%.2f, (2)/(1)=%.2f, (3)/(1)=%.2f' %(time1/time1,time2/time1,time3/time1)

    times1_all.append(times1)
    times2_all.append(times2)
    times3_all.append(times3)

times1_mean = np.mean(times1_all, axis=0)
times2_mean = np.mean(times2_all, axis=0)
times3_mean = np.mean(times3_all, axis=0)
```

The results of this test are shown in the image below, which shows the elapsed time of different algorithms as a function of the image pixel number (I only quote the side number of pixels in the x-axis). As expected, the bigger the image, the longer it takes to do the job. However, it is clear that there are systematic differences amongst the algorithms. For any number of pixels, the algorithms proposed by @randomir and @Ofer perform better than that proposed by @user1717828. So, According to this metric, @Ofer and $randomir are equivalent.

[image: Comparison of algorithms]

Comment: `time` is not really appropriate to measure performance. For this purpose the `timeit` module is in the standard library. Using a high number of repeats and runs with timeit helps to get **really accurate timings**.

Comment: I bet I will get the same answer. I am averaging over several trials here.

Comment: Then another point: The average is a bad measure for performance runs over many repeats. Usually you should take the [minimum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.repeat).

Comment: But I would be really interested if you get the same results. I cross-checked `time` vs. `timeit` on some occasions and `time` often was 10-20% slower and contain much more outlier. I don't try to annoy you here but if you add an answer comparing the performance it should at least be done right.

Answer (score 1):

You can mask (either with `>0` or `==255` or really anything else) then convert to type `int`:

```
npa = np.array([0,255,0,255,255,255,0])
npa
array([  0, 255,   0, 255, 255, 255,   0])


(npa>0).astype('int')
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0])
```

Comment: You can do `-a.astype(np.int8)`, for this specific case, the overflow would work exactly right.